# Multi variable in multi processing with one common

Tags: python, sql, multiprocessing, arguments

I have a script in python and a function that I need to execute with multiprocessing, however, one of the parameter (df) of this function is the same for each call. Let me explain with the code :

```
def main(): 
    for country in all_countries:
        df = SqlManager().sql_query('MyDb', "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Country=''")
        args = [(
            df,
            lvl,
            timescale,
            adm_code
        ) for lvl in ['Country', 'Region', 'County']
            for timescale in ['month', 'week']
            for adm_code in list(df[lvl].unique())
        ]
        pool = Pool(cpu_count())
        entry_list = list(tqdm(pool.imap(parallel_func, args), total=len(args))
```

where

```
def parallel_func(args):
    return function_to_run(*args)

def function_to_run(df, lvl, timescale, adm_code):
    """my code"""
```

probleme with that is my df is very big (more than 50 millions of rows), and with this process I store it 10000 times in args while it is exactly the same one everywhere
I also don't want to do the SQL call into my parallel function, because what I will win in memory I will lose by calling SQL several time for the same data

I try to use global variable, but again as I am working in //, they didn't share the same variable.

Comment: Does the table contain 50m rows or does the query return 50m rows?

Comment: both I guess, the query return 50mrows and they are store into the df

Comment: You say "guess"?

Comment: I mean it is both, the dataframe as 50m of rows because the query return 50m of rows

Comment: Why do you have this loop: *for country in all_countries* ?

Comment: just because I need to apply that for all the country, and the total database is 500 go so I cannot load it in one shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255946/discussion-between-codist-and-kilag).

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on a method to make a Pandas dataframe sharable across multiple processes described [in this article](https://e-dorigatti.github.io/python/2020/06/19/multiprocessing-large-objects.html). The principle class is `SharedPandasDataFrame`, used in the following way:

```py
# A sharable instance based on a Numpy array stored in shared memory:
shared_df = SharedPandasDataFrame(df) # sharable instance
# Reconstitute the dataframe from the sharable instance: 
df = shared_df.read()
```

It is the `shared_df` instance that must be passed to a process and that process can then reconstitute the dataframe from that using its `read` method.

```py
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import multiprocessing as mp

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

class SharedNumpyArray:
    '''
    Wraps a numpy array so that it can be shared quickly among processes,
    avoiding unnecessary copying and (de)serializing.
    '''
    def __init__(self, array):
        '''
        Creates the shared memory and copies the array therein
        '''
        # create the shared memory location of the same size of the array
        self._shared = SharedMemory(create=True, size=array.nbytes)

        # save data type and shape, necessary to read the data correctly
        self._dtype, self._shape = array.dtype, array.shape

        # create a new numpy array that uses the shared memory we created.
        # at first, it is filled with zeros
        res = np.ndarray(
            self._shape, dtype=self._dtype, buffer=self._shared.buf
        )

        # copy data from the array to the shared memory. numpy will
        # take care of copying everything in the correct format
        res[:] = array[:]

    def read(self):
        '''
        Reads the array from the shared memory without unnecessary copying.
        '''
        # simply create an array of the correct shape and type,
        # using the shared memory location we created earlier
        return np.ndarray(self._shape, self._dtype, buffer=self._shared.buf)

    def copy(self):
        '''
        Returns a new copy of the array stored in shared memory.
        '''
        return np.copy(self.read_array())

    def unlink(self):
        '''
        Releases the allocated memory. Call when finished using the data,
        or when the data was copied somewhere else.
        '''
        self._shared.close()
        self._shared.unlink()

class SharedPandasDataFrame:
    '''
    Wraps a pandas dataframe so that it can be shared quickly among processes,
    avoiding unnecessary copying and (de)serializing.
    '''
    def __init__(self, df):
        '''
        Creates the shared memory and copies the dataframe therein
        '''
        self._values = SharedNumpyArray(df.values)
        self._index = df.index
        self._columns = df.columns

    def read(self):
        '''
        Reads the dataframe from the shared memory
        without unnecessary copying.
        '''
        return pd.DataFrame(
            self._values.read(),
            index=self._index,
            columns=self._columns
        )

    def copy(self):
        '''
        Returns a new copy of the dataframe stored in shared memory.
        '''
        return pd.DataFrame(
            self._values.copy(),
            index=self._index,
            columns=self._columns
        )

    def unlink(self):
        '''
        Releases the allocated memory. Call when finished using the data,
        or when the data was copied somewhere else.
        '''
        self._values.unlink()


def parallel_func(tpl):
    # Unpack:
    shared_df, lvl, timescale, adm_code = tpl
    # reconstitute the dataframe:
    df = shared_df.read()
    ...


def main():
    for country in all_countries:
        df = SqlManager().sql_query('MyDb', "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Country=''")
        shared_df = SharedPandasDataFrame(df)
        args = [(
            shared_df,
            lvl,
            timescale,
            adm_code
        ) for lvl in ['Country', 'Region', 'County']
            for timescale in ['month', 'week']
            for adm_code in list(df[lvl].unique())
        ]
        # If you need to access the sharable dataframe, uncomment out the following
        # df = shared_df.read()

        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            # Add missing )
            entry_list = list(tqdm(pool.imap(parallel_func, args), total=len(args)))
        # Destroy shared memory rendering shared_df unusable:
        shared_df.unlink()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```